# Does the entirety of the efficiency of an aerospike engine occur in the lower atmosphere, or are the advantages in a vacuum as well?

Tags: rockets, propulsion, aerospike

I mean, it's called an **aero**spike engine for a reason, I guess, but are there any other advantages to the engine that accrue in space? Is the bell configuration better in a vacuum?

Comment: [Some people](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/x-33/aero_faq.htm) use the term **aero**spike only for _truncated spike nozzles with gas generator exhaust exiting at the base of the spike_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The built-in altitude-compensating nature of the aerospike is its primary advantage.

tl;dr: It's better than a bell at low altitudes, and as good as one at high altitudes.

> However, many claim that the ultimate strength of the aerospike nozzle is its inherent altitude compensation capability, as shown below.

[image]

> This ideal behavior results from the fact that the outer plume
> boundary of the primary flow is acted upon only by the ambient
> pressure of the atmosphere.
>
> Recall from our discussion of aerospike
> thrust characteristics, high ambient pressure at low altitudes forces
> the exhaust inward increasing the pressure on the "centerbody" and the
> centerbody component of thrust. In addition, the base region is open
> to high ambient pressure resulting in a greater "base" thrust
> component. At design pressure, the flow becomes column shaped, much
> like a bell nozzle, for maximum efficiency. When operating at low
> ambient pressure (at high altitude or in a vacuum), the flow is
> constrained by expansion/compression waves that direct the exhaust
> axially to maintain the thrust force on the centerbody.
>
> At low
> pressures, however, the nozzle operates in a "closed wake" state.
> Since the base is not subject to a high ambient pressure, there is no
> altitude compensation benefit, and the aerospike behaves like a high
> area ratio bell nozzle. **Thus, in theory at least, the aerospike nozzle
> meets or exceeds the performance of the bell nozzle at all operating
> pressures.**

(emphasis mine)

[Source](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/design/aerospike/compensation.shtml)